# Project Centennial - Access Denied when running Desktop App Convertor

Tags: win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

This is the error I am getting when I run the convertor:

```
Exception calling "RunIsolatedProcessWithMappedDirectoryAndExport" with "6" argument(s): "Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" At C:\Users\Harsimran\Downloads\DesktopAppConverter\converter_util\Sequencer.ps1:140 char:9
+         $installerExitCode = [Microsoft.Centennial.Tools.DesktopAppCo ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I am able to silently run the installer and install my program, so the error has to do with Project Centennial. I am not sure what to do.

I could not find the appropriate tags for this question, so it might seem vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually a known issue in Windows Insider Build 14332.  The new insider build in the fast ring should fix this issue.