# DesktopAppConverter.ps1 -setup fails

Tags: windows-installer, win-universal-app

When I run the 14342 compatible version of the DesktopAppConverter utility to setup the base image (14342), I get these two errors after a long while extracting the image:

```
Remove-NetNat : The requested operation is not supported.
At C:\Users\hillr\Downloads\DesktopAppConverter\converter_util\CWACNetworkSetup.ps1:143 char:9
+         Remove-NetNat -Confirm:$False
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MSFT_NetNat (InstanceID = "DockerNAT;0"):root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetN
   at) [Remove-NetNat], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 50,Remove-NetNat

New-ContainerNetwork : The object already exists.
At C:\Users\hillr\Downloads\DesktopAppConverter\converter_util\CWACNetworkSetup.ps1:102 char:16
+ ...  $network = New-ContainerNetwork -Name $NetworkName -Mode NAT -Subnet ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-ContainerNetwork], VirtualizationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.Containers.PowerShell.Cmdlets.NewContainerNetwork
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?  I can't successfully run the converter against our installer.  I get:

```
Exception calling "RunIsolatedProcessWithMappedDirectoryAndExport" with "6" argument(s): "could not find NAT network"
At C:\Users\hillr\Downloads\DesktopAppConverter\converter_util\Sequencer.ps1:141 char:9
+         $installerExitCode = [Microsoft.Centennial.Tools.DesktopAppCo ...
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Exception
```

Comment: I have a different, but probably similar error. It first fails to load some 'vcompute.dll', then states that `New-ContainerNetwork` is not recognized as a powershell command. Do you happen to use a 32-bit environment? I do.

Comment: No, I'm running x64 Windows and a x64 PowerShell prompt.

Comment: Hmm, the FullyQualifiedErrorId differs, but otherwise this looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36945727/project-centennial-access-denied-when-running-desktop-app-convertor

Comment: I was able to get this to work in Windows 10 build 14352 but IIRC I had to remove the existing container networks.  I also had Docker for Windows Beta installed and I installed that.  Not sure which resulted in this starting to work for me.